# upload files to a specific parameter only

Tags: grails, file-upload

I am uploading files into a list. however I want to be able to specify to which parameter I am uploading so next time I access it I see the files I uploaded into that path only:

for example I have this dropdown menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list' params='[fruit:"apple"]'>apple</g:link></li>
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list' params='[fruit:"blueberry"]'>bluberry</g:link></li>
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list' params='[fruit:"strawberry"]'>strawberry</g:link></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><g:link resource="gm">v4sa</g:link></li>
</ul>
```

if I click on apple. and I upload a file. I want to be able to see those files only for params.fruit == apple

which means in this URL only : http://localhost:8080/file_down/document/list?fruit=apple

If I go to the URL of blueberry, I could upload files also, but in the list I can only see files uploaded for bluberry:

Here are my upload controllers:

```
class DocumentController {

    def index = {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list() {
        params.max = 10
        [documentInstanceList: Document.list(params), documentInstanceTotal: Document.count()]
    }


    def upload() {
        def uploadedFile = request.getFile('file')
        if(uploadedFile.isEmpty())
        {
            flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
        }
        else
        {
            def documentInstance = new Document()
            documentInstance.filename = uploadedFile.originalFilename
            //fileSize
            documentInstance.fileSize = uploadedFile.size
            documentInstance.fileSize = documentInstance.fileSize/(1024*1024)
            documentInstance.fullPath = grailsApplication.config.uploadFolder + documentInstance.filename
            uploadedFile.transferTo(new File(documentInstance.fullPath))
            documentInstance.save()
        }
        redirect (action: 'list')
    }
}
```

and this is my list.gsp that shows the files in the table, it is the same table for all of the different parameters, and same gsp page, just shows different files :

```
<tbody>
    <g:each in="${documentInstanceList}" status="i" var="documentInstance">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td><g:link action="download" id="${documentInstance.id}">${documentInstance.filename}</g:link></td>
        <td><g:link id="${documentInstance.id}">${documentInstance.fileSize}MB</g:link></td>
        <td><g:formatDate date="${documentInstance.uploadDate}" /></td>
        <td><span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="delete" controller="Document" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" /></span></td>
    </tr>
    </g:each>
</tbody>
```

What should I do to upload only into one specific parameter and show it only at that parameter ?

**EDIT**
this is my upload form:

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="upload" class="save" value="upload" />
                    <g:hiddenField name="fruit" value="${params.fruit?: 'defaultValue'}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:uploadForm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload file by form, so add hidden field with name of fruit:

```
<g:hiddenField name="fruit" value="${params.fruit ?: 'defaultValue'}"/>
```

If by ajax, so add to data params:

```
data:{file:file, fruit:"${params.fruit ?: defaultValue}",..
```

defaultValue need for resolve errors. Good luck :)

Comment: I added the hidden field in my upload form please check my EDIT. however when I login as apple and upload something for apple, it still shows for another parameter fruit in the list. for example it still shows for blueberry. I want it to be shown for only one. Did I not put it right in the upload form ?

Comment: you should add logic to controller, that it take params.fruit and save it